# To redirect laptop video output and audio output to TV

Tags: laptop, tv

Although i read many related questions here at superuser, but i could not find an answer in them, so asking here.

I have a HP-Pavillion laptop. It has a below video related ports - 
S-Video output port, a normal 15 pin female VGA port. It has below audio related ports - Speaker out, Headphone out, microphone in.

Now i want to connect this laptop to a TV at home, so that whatever i play on laptop(say some movies), i can view them on my TV screen which is relatively bigger(21 inch), and also the accompanying audio being played on the laptop, i want to hear from the TV speakers.

My TV has the RCA connector input(Video, Left Audio,Right audio).Other than this it does not seem to have any other input connector.

1.)How can i connect my laptop video and audio output to this TV i have?

-AD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a cable like this [SVIDEO to Composite](http://www.startech.com/item/SVID2RCAMM10-10ft-S-Video-to-Composite-Video-Adapter-Cable-Male-to-Male.aspx)  and an [3.5 to RCA](http://www.startech.com/item/MU6MMRCA-6-ft-PC-to-Stereo-Component-Cable-35mm-Male-to-2x-RCA-Male.aspx)

That should do it for you